# Android design support navigation drawer selecting multiple items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I want to know if there is a way to tell the design support navigation drawer to only mark one item as selected, when I have sub-items which contain more items.

Code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
            android:title="Item 1"
            android:checked="true"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
            android:title="Item 2" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="Subtitle 1">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:title="Item 3" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_4"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:title="Item 4" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_5"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
                android:title="Item 5" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I have `Item 1` selected by default and it is the first fragment that appears when launching the app. When I press on an item in a subtitle, `Item 5` for example, `Item 1` still has the darker background and is colored in the accent color, while `Item 5` is only colored in the accent color without the dark background. How can I archive that only one items gets marked at one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the group needs to be around all items like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:title="Item 1"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:title="Item 2" />


<item android:title="Subtitle 1">
    <menu>
     <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
            android:title="Item 3" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_4"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
            android:title="Item 4" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_5"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
            android:title="Item 5" />
     </group>
    </menu>
  </item>
 </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: @qwertz you are welcome - sorry for my slip the first time